# What are the valid values (and meaning) of the async attribute of html script tag?

Tags: html, asynchronous

I need to know if a  tag is async by parsing html. I got a problem that I can't find any document about the valid value (and meaning) of `async` attribute.

What I know is that for async the valid value is:

- async
- async="async"

for non-async:

- async="false"

what does `async=""` mean? and any other value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/script.html#script.attrs.async) it is:

> async = "async" or "" (empty string) or empty

(where empty means `async`, without assigning a value)

Its meaning:

> Specifies that the script should be executed asynchronously, as soon as it becomes available.

So the browser should attempt to download the script file, without waiting to continue parsing the page. It loads the script as soon as it is done downloading.

Comment: so async="false" is actually not a valid value?

Comment: What does the specification say? Only the values given there are valid.